# Securing Google Cloud Functions using WSO2

Tags: python, wso2, google-cloud-functions, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm writing an application (web and mobile) where I would like to use WSO2 for user authentication, authorization and SSO.

My mobile app will authenticate the users against the WSO2-is.

All the API's used by the app are google cloud functions written in python.

I would like to bring a security layer to my GCF's.

From my understanding I can use WSO2-am as a bridge between the app and the GCF to provide security, but I would like to leverage the high scalability of the GCF archicteture and avoid the WSO2-am being a bottleneck.

Is it possible use the WSO2-am and make the GCF to check the permissions access against it, allowing the app calling the API directly instead of using the WSO2-am as a bridge ?

If yes, may you provide some documentation/blogpost/whatever that could help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WSO2 APIM, the gateway does all the authentication and authorization stuff when the requests go through it (to the backend).

So, in the case of,

(1) OAuth2 tokens, the gateway talks to the key manager to validate the token, subscription (API-to-Application) and token scopes.

(2) Self-contained JWT tokens, the gateway can do all these validations itself.

So now in your case, since you don't want to send the requests through the gateway, you have to do what gateway does, within the cloud function itself. In that case, the JWT tokens will be the best choice as they can be validated without connecting to the key manager.

In addition to that, the gateway keeps a token cache so that it doesn't have to validate the same token again and again. You can have a similar cache (if possible) within your cloud functions too. However, in your case, you will have to externalize the cache due to the short-lifetime nature of cloud functions.

Here is the gateway code[1] which does the token, scopes and subscription validations. You can use it as a guide to write yours.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/master/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/security/jwt/JWTValidator.java